# In a pandas data frame, Is there a way to find the amount of duplicate pairings that exist between rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, you know the possible values that can be under A and those that can be under B and you want to know the number of instance each pairing occurs.

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | C |
| Second | 2 | F |
| Third | 2 | C |
| Fourth | 1 | C |
| Fifth | 2 | F |

**Output:**

1,C = 2

2,F = 2

2,C = 1

Comment: `df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['Name'].count())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.count.html):

```
grouping = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['Name'].count()
```

Output:

```
>>> grouping
A  B
1  C    2
2  C    1
   F    2
Name: Name, dtype: int64

>>> grouping[(1, 'C')]
2

>>> grouping[(2, 'C')]
1

>>> grouping[(2, 'F')]
2
```

Comment: Is there a way to have it as a data frame or dictionary as opposed to a series? I tried to_frame() but it just create one column under 'Name'.

Comment: @Reece try this: `df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['Name'].count().reset_index()`